# How to create a .deb and/or an .exe file with electron-react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, build, electron, electron-react-boilerplate

I created an app with the following command:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate.git myapp
```

installed the node modules

```
$ npm install
```

and then I built the executables

```
$ npm run package
```

Now I find the linux files including the binary here:

```
$ ls myapp/release/build/linux-unpacked
```

and the app files for the mac here:

```
$ ls myapp/release/build
```

**What way there is to generate a .deb file and/or a .exe file, too?**